# Collect results of a map operation in a Map using Collectors.toMap or groupingBy

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've got a list of type `List<A>` and with map operation getting a collective list of type `List<B>` for all A elements merged in one list.

```
List<A> listofA = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, ...]

List<B> listofB = listofA.stream()
  .map(a -> repo.getListofB(a))
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

without flatmap

```
List<List<B>> listOflistofB = listofA.stream()
  .map(a -> repo.getListofB(a))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to collect the results as a map of type `Map<A, List<B>>` and so far trying with various `Collectors.toMap` or `Collectors.groupingBy` options but not able to get the desired result.

Comment: Do you have repeated `A` elements in your `List<A>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `toMap` collector with a bounded method reference to get what you need. Also notice that this solution assumes you don't have repeated A instances in your source container. If that precondition holds this solution would give you the desired result. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<A, Collection<B>> resultMap = listofA.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), repo::getListofB);
```

If you have duplicate A elements, then you have to use this merge function in addition to what is given above. The merge function deals with key conflicts if any.

```
Map<A, Collection<B>> resultMap = listofA.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), repo::getListofB, 
            (a, b) -> {
                a.addAll(b);
                return a;
        }));
```

And here's a much more succinct Java9 approach which uses the `flatMapping` collector to handle repeated A elements.

```
Map<A, List<B>> aToBmap = listofA.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                Collectors.flatMapping(a -> getListofB(a).stream(), 
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Hey, nice you've added how to handle duplicates! I was adding an answer with that, I will let it because I think it complements yours, cheers!

Comment: Yes, your comment was helpful. Good catch !

Answer (score 2):

It would be straight forward,

```
listofA.stream().collect(toMap(Function.identity(), a -> getListofB(a)));
```

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, I'm showing what happens if you have repeated `A` elements in your `List<A> listofA` list.

Actually, if there were duplicates in `listofA`, the following code would throw an `IllegalStateException`:

```
Map<A, Collection<B>> resultMap = listofA.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Function.identity(), 
                            repo::getListofB);
```

The exception might be thrown because `Collectors.toMap` doesn't know how to *merge* values when there is a collision in the keys (i.e. when the key mapper function returns duplicates, as it would be the case for `Function.identity()` if there were repeated elements in the `listofA` list).

This is clearly stated [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to `Object.equals(Object)`), an `IllegalStateException` is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use [`toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)) instead.

The docs also give us the solution: in case there are repeated elements, we need to provide a way to merge values. Here's one such way:

```
Map<A, Collection<B>> resultMap = listofA.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Function.identity(), 
                            a -> new ArrayList<>(repo.getListofB(a)),
                            (left, right) -> {
                                left.addAll(right);
                                return left;
                            });
```

This uses the overloaded version of `Collectors.toMap` that accepts a *merge function* as its third argument. Within the merge function, `Collection.addAll` is being used to add the `B` elements of each repeated `A` element into a unqiue list for each `A`.

In the value mapper function, a new `ArrayList` is created, so that the original `List<B>` of each `A` is not mutated. Also, as we're creating an `Arraylist`, we know in advance that it can be mutated (i.e. we can add elements to it later, in case there are duplicates in `listofA`).

Answer (score 1):

To collect a `Map` where keys are the `A` objects unchanged, and the values are the list of corresponding `B` objects, you can replace the `toList()` collector by the following collector :

```
toMap(Function.identity(), a -> repo.getListOfB(a))
```

The **first** argument defines how to compute the **key** from the original object : `identity()` takes the original object of the stream unchanged.

The **second** argument defines how the **value** is computed, so here it just consists of a call to your method that transforms a `A` to a list of `B`.

Since the `repo` method takes only one parameter, you can also improve clarity by replacing the lambda with a method reference :

```
toMap(Function.identity(), repo::getListOfB)
```

Comment: Thanks @kgautron, your answer is correct and clearly explained. I accepted the other answer because I saw it first.